# Objects not showing on camera or in render

Tags: rendering, camera

Firstly, I'm on MacOS Sonoma 14.2 with Blender 4.0 and I'm using the Laptop keyboard, so not all keyboard shortcuts work for me.

I have created several objects and placed my camera to look on them. There's a spotlight shining light on them on the left. As you can see from the image, the camera has my object in view. The spotlight is shining on the object. Everything apart from the lowest box has a texture.
[image: 20th century fox Logo style font objects displayed in 3Dviewer, the view is along where the camera views]

The Problem: when I go to camera mode, I just see an empty stage, with the grid and the origin, but no object, which should definitely be there. The same happens if I render the image but then it's just an empty screen in my background color. [image: Image of camera view, origin and grid are visible, but not the object which should be there]

Now, I'm new to blender, so I might just be overlooking something, but I've googled and tried all fixes suggested. My object is definitely visible, not hidden, my clipping distance is more than enough, the texture is not the issue (I tried with a different one), all my objects + light + camera are in the same layer.

Please, does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can get my objects to appear in camera view? I'm happy to provide the file, if there's a way to do that.

Comment: It looks like your camera is not positioned directly in front of your 3d object. Select the camera and then click the Rotate option under the Tool menu at the left of your workspace This will allow you to tilt the camera down until you see your object. Let me know if that doesn't work. :)

Comment: Or it may be possible that you have a different camera as your active camera, not the one in front of your object.

Comment: You can share your file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Starry-EyedDonut So I tried many times to tilt the camera, but it never worked. However, in a last attempt to prove that something is wrong I moved the camera much closer to the object and voila, it's there. I set the clipping distance to 10000, so I don't know why it didn't show before, the camera wasn't THAT far away, but at least I can see my object now. :) 
Now I just gotta figure out my light source. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @Starry-EyedDonut The camera shown in the screenshot is the active camera, you can recognize this by the filled triangle on top. If it wasn't the active camera, the triangle would just be showing the outline edges.

Comment: @Annika Which clipping distance? There is a _Clip Start_ and also _End_, then you have these settings separately for the camera and the viewport as well.